# Why does it take 4 seconds for Entity Framework to start executing a query?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework for an application where we have a fairly complex inheritance model and we are using Table Per Type Inheritance.

This works pretty well because we can just do a query for the base type and get back the concrete types.

The downside is that the EF query that gets generated is very large and has a lot of outer joins.

Right now a query to get a single object is taking about 4 seconds to return. The interesting thing is that the execution of the actual TSQL is only taking ~500ms. I'm basing this off of the output logging from EF.

We are using this code to do the logging to the console:

```
Database.Log = s =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
};
```

And in the log for this example it will usually look something like:

> Opened connection at 8/4/2016 2:59:07 PM -07:00
>
> [TSQL CODE OUTPUT HERE]
>
> -- Executing at 8/4/2016 2:59:13 PM -07:00
>
> -- Completed in 772 ms with result: SqlDataReader

So I'm trying to understand why it takes so long to start executing the query. Is this just EF having to work to generate the complex SQL statement? Is there any way to cache those statements?

NOTE: I've tried implemented the precompiled views and it did not change the performance on the individual queries.

UPDATE: The issue of object materialization was brought up so I tested it again and loaded an id that wasn't in the system. It still takes 4-7 seconds from the connection being opened to the query execution starting. No change.

Comment: Note that materializing entities from the query result can also take a considerable amount of time. Try to measure the time it takes to execute a realistic query that returns an empty result.

Comment: Tested and that isn't the issue. Thanks.